# How to add folders except few using git add

Tags: git, github

I am getting this error in VSCode stating "

> This git repository has too many active changes, only a subset of git
> features will be enabled

"

I am probably getting this because of my eclipse .metadata folder and folders like .history and .settings.

I wanted to exclude these folders while adding the others in git repo so I tried this :

```
git add -- . :!.history :!.metadata :!.settings
```

and this too,

```
git add --all --:!.history :!.metadata :!.settings
```

but getting error

> bash: !.history: event not found

How do I solve it, I have updated my git software but it doesn't seem to be fixing it.

Comment: Add the names of the folders you want to ignore in your .gitignore file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting is not specific to `git` but specific to `bash` where the `!` character is related to `bash` history, to achieve what you are trying to do, you can escape the `!` with `\`,

So something like

```sh
git add --all --:\!.history :\!.metadata :\!.settings
```

But a cleaner approach will be to use a `.gitignore` file and add entries for each of the above directories for that.

So your `.gitignore` would look something like the following -

```
# contents of .gitignore
.history
.metadata
.settings
```

This `.gitignore` file should be at the root of our repository.

Comment: .gitignore is indeed a better option. Thank you!